# Increase Performance of Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an stored procedure return about 5 million record from database 
what is the best way to increase the performance ,'

```
    Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPhoneNumbers]
         @SendersList SendersIdList ReadOnly ,  
         @MessageList MessageIdList ReadOnly,
         @ClientList ClientsIdList ReadOnly   AS        
    select distinct PH.PhoneNumber from XMLImported xmi  
    inner join @MessageList MessageIdList on xmi.MessageId = MessageIdList.ID  
            inner join @SendersList SendersIdList on xmi.SenderId = SendersIdList.ID 
            inner join @ClientList ClientsIdList on xmi.ClientId = ClientsIdList.ID
 inner join Phones PH on PH.Id = xmi.PhoneId
```

I'm Using User-Defined Data Type for each variable and using inner join insted of in clause to increase the performance, performance increased a little but still not as required ,

I'm adding index also for the fields

> PS.
>
> > SendersIdList,MessageIdList,ClientsIdList all these are User-Defined
> >     Table Type with one field ID,
> >
> > XMLImported contains about 50 million record

any suggest for solve my issue?

Edit Attach execution plan 
[image]

Comment: did you have a look on the execution plan? Are there any Fulltable Scans maybe?

Comment: Please add an execution plan, and perhaps descriptions of the types you use. Without additional information, it's impossible for us to make useful suggestions, purely based on what you supplied.

Comment: My first instinct is "don't return 5 million records" - if this is being consumed by some automated process, find some way to provide it with delta updates rather than the whole list. If this is being consumed by a human, then it's misdesigned, because nobody is going to look through a list of 5 million records.

Comment: Check if all three id columns have indexes in where clause. Also, check your percent of index fragmentation. SELECT Object_name (object_id) from sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL) WHERE Object_name (object_id) is not null and avg_fragmentation_in_percent &gt; 30. You may need to rebuild these indexes if they belong to table in question. Do you have enough server memory to run this query? You can consider creating actual tables instead of table variables for join clause.

Comment: @SchmitzIT I edit the question and add execution plan

Comment: @SchmitzIT - the tables with table scans on them are the table-valued parameters. UDTTs can't define any indexes, so optimization opportunities there are limited.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever My bad. Will remove my comment (am trying to juggle a few things at once, so I confused two things, unfortunately )

Comment: There is a inner join in there that takes 48%. Which column is it joining with. Does that column have index on it. Can you try breaking this query into three queries and check if resultset takes less time or not. Also, you can check individual execution plans then. And if three queries work well, combine resultset with SQL UNION operator.

Comment: How many records in the three list parameters?

Comment: @BensaysNotoPoliticsonSO between 10 to 1000 debend

Comment: Can you use [pastetheplan](http://pastetheplan.com) to share the execution plan? Also, as a quick fix I might try and add `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` at the end of your query. You might suffer from the infamous "parameter sniffing", since your parameter input varies quite "so much"

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure the fields you are joining on are indexed, (e.g. a primary key or unique constraint). In your case that's `Phones.ID`, and on `XMLImported` `ClientID`, `MessageId`, `SenderID`, `PhoneID`. A covering index on the fields of interest should do it:

```
ALTER TABLE XMLImported 
ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_XmlImported_MSCP UNIQUE (MessageID, SenderID, ClientID, PhoneID)
```

If that combination is not unique, add the primary key to the list.

You can add indexes to user defined table types by adding primary keys or unique constraints.

If you already have a unique field or combination of fields, you can use that.

For example:

```
 Create type SendersIDList as Table(
    ID bigint PRIMARY KEY
 )
```

Another example:

```
Create Type TableType as Table(
   keyField1 varchar(10),
   keyField2 varchar(20),
   nonKeyField varchar(20),
   Primary Key (keyField1, KeyField2),
   Unique (nonKeyField, KeyField1, keyField2)
)
```

This will create a clustered index on `keyField1, keyField2`, and a covering index on `nonKeyField, keyfield1, keyField2`

If you don't have a unique field or combination of fields, you can add an identity column to the type.